# Understanding fread() to store rgb pixel values

Tags: c, pointers, fread

The for loop should be replaced with a fread I believe, however, I am very unclear on how fread will work.

How does fread know the value of green pixel @ given location and where to save the value. My understanding is that I have a chunk of heap memory, a rectangle has a tbd number of pixels. Each pixel has 3 values. How will fread (or any other method I can use)?

If anyone could just explain how the fread line below would work with my code? This is for an assignment, I am just trying to understand what is going on since it is one we will be building on.

`fread(pixelD, sizeof(Pixel), width*height, file);`

```c
typdef struct
{       
        unsigned char green;
        unsigned char blue;
        unsigned char red;
}pixelD;

typedef struct
{       
        pixelD * pixel;
} Color;

Image * ReadImage(char *filename)
{
  int width, height, maxval;
  int imgSize = width * height * sizeof(pixel); 

  //fscanf line was given by prof 
  fscanf(f_in, "%s\n%d %d\n%d\n", magicNum, &width, &height, &maxval);
  pixel = malloc(imgSize);                       
  for(int i = 0; i <imgSize; i++)
  {
     pixel.green = pixel[i];  ???? 
     pixel.blue = ; 
     pixel.red = ; 
  }
}
```

Comment: `fread()` doesn't know anything about the file you read, it just reads a block of data from it. It's up to you to interpret that block.

Comment: The `fscanf()` line implies that it's a text file. `fread()` is used with binary files, it's not generally useful with text files.

Comment: You need to set `imgSize` *after* you read in `width` and `height`.

Comment: If it is a text file I don't understand how can he read an image data from it.

Comment: There's no declaration of `pixel`.

Comment: Image data is numbers, the numbers are represented as text like `123 25 200`

Comment: Image data also contain and bad numbers - zeros

Comment: If code is to read binary data, be sure to open the file in _binary_ mode.  `f_in = fopen(...., "rb");`

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you are reading a [PPM file](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html).

Read the header doing something like this:

```
int width, height, max;
my_assert(3==fscanf(f_in, "P6%d%d%d ", &width, &height, &max));
/* TODO: error handling */
```

The format specifiers tells it to read the expected magic number ("P6"), then second, third and fourth words as integers (implicitly skipping any whitespace between), and then consume a whitespace ("mostly a newline" according PPM) to set the file read position to where the binary data starts. You should probably make sure width/height/max being within what your application expects and can cope with.

And then read the rest of the data into memory. `fread` read from the current read position `size*count` bytes; no formatting:

```
int channel_width = max < 256 ? 1 : 2; /* PPM channel width can be either 1- or 2-byte */
int rgb = 3;
int imgsize = width*height*rgb*channel_width;
void* texture = malloc(imgsize);
my_assert(imgsize==fread(texture, 1, imgsize, f_in));
/* do something with the texture memory */
```

At that point you can just cast the texture pointer to whatever struct you like to use, e.g. `pixel1D* pixs = texture` (just be careful if channels are 2-byte long since your posted struct is not). I find a structure carrying the meta and a typeless memory block more flexible since mostly working with OpenGL. Maybe that is what you meant to do with the `Image` type.

The code is completely untested. Have fun debugging it.

Comment: Nitpick: never `assert()` any code that you want to actually run. The NDEBUG define removes `assert` and everything in its parentheses. And it often gets set in release/optimized builds when you least expect it.

Comment: @ZanLynx `#undef NDEBUG` ;-) But seriously though I have found no good alternative. `expr ? exit(-1):0` is just sad... got any tip?

Comment: Yes. Write proper if statement checks and call perror() and exit(). If it seems too wordy write your own macro. But not assert().

Comment: @ZanLynx Edited.